# cascading updates in mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, key, cascade, relational

Been trying to wrap my head around this one, but have been unsuccessful.

Basically I am trying to create a database containing only two tables.
The first table is the logins table, and contains columns:

```
User ID
Username
Password
First Name
Last Name
```

The second table is the vote table, and contains columns:

```
User ID
Vote 1
Vote 2
Vote 3
```

etc. etc.

Is there anyway that I can relate these tables with the User ID as a primary key, that can cascade update/delete, so that when I add an entry into the logins table, it auto creates an entry in the votes table with the same User ID, and default value for all the vote columns?

I could add the votes to the main table, but wanted to seperate them out as much as possible, as not everyone will be creating votes.

Many thanks
Eds

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an insert [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) on the `logins` table.

This will execute each time a row is inserted into the `logins` table. You can specify what you'd like the trigger to do. In this case you can create the trigger to insert a single row into your `vote` table using the id just created in the `login` table along with your default values.

So something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER logins_default_vote AFTER INSERT ON logins
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO vote (UserID,Vote1,Vote2,Vote3) 
VALUES (NEW.UserId,'vote1 default','vote2 default','vote3 default');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cascade updates, you'll need to use a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO logins (username, passhash, salt, `first name`, `last name`)
  VALUES ('$username', SHA2(CONCAT('$salt','$password'),512), '$salt',
          '$firstname', '$lastname');
SELECT @userid:= LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO votes (userid) VALUES (@userid);

COMMIT;
```

Make sure you have default values set in the table definition of the votes table.

Note the use of salted hashed passwords.